# How do you display the IP address for a specific interface?

Tags: java, ip, network-interface

So I'm trying to programmically get an IP address from one specific interface and display it in a text field. Problem is that it lists several. How do you iterate through and get the IP addresses for the Dual Band Wireless-AC 3160?

```
Dual Band Wireless-AC 3160 172.16.36.50
Dual Band Wireless-AC 3160 fe80:0:0:0:8877:2e6a:e4a1:c24f%wlan0
Virtual Ethernet Adapter for VMnet1 192.168.31.1
Virtual Ethernet Adapter for VMnet1 fe80:0:0:0:592c:71ac:f8d9:5899%eth3
Virtual Ethernet Adapter for VMnet8 192.168.245.1
Virtual Ethernet Adapter for VMnet8 fe80:0:0:0:ed34:4a7:cb5c:16ce%eth4
```

Here is the code that I used to display the interfaces:

```
String ip;
        try {
            Enumeration<NetworkInterface> interfaces = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces();
            int position;
            while (interfaces.hasMoreElements()) {
                NetworkInterface iface = interfaces.nextElement();
                //This filters out the interfaces
                // filters out 127.0.0.1 and inactive interfaces
                if (iface.isLoopback() || !iface.isUp())
                    continue;

                Enumeration<InetAddress> addresses = iface.getInetAddresses();
                while(addresses.hasMoreElements()) {
                    InetAddress addr = addresses.nextElement();
                    ip = addr.getHostAddress();

                    System.out.println(iface.getDisplayName() + " " + ip);
                }
            }
        } catch (SocketException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I Solved it by doing the following. Thanks.

```
String ip;

        try {
            Enumeration<NetworkInterface> interfaces = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces();
            int position =0;
            while (interfaces.hasMoreElements()) {
                NetworkInterface iface = interfaces.nextElement();
                //This filters out the interfaces
                // filters out 127.0.0.1 and inactive interfaces
                if (iface.isLoopback() || !iface.isUp())
                    continue;

                Enumeration<InetAddress> addresses = iface.getInetAddresses();
                while(addresses.hasMoreElements()) {
                    InetAddress addr = addresses.nextElement();
                    ip = addr.getHostAddress();
                    position++;

                    if (position == 0 ) {
                        System.out.println(iface.getDisplayName() + " " + ip);
                    }

                    else{
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (SocketException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
```

Comment: So you just want the first interface in the list, no matter what it is?

Answer (score 1):

You get two IP addresses because the interface has two IP addresses. In general there could be even more.

If you want to list only the IPv4 addresses you can check if the address is `instanceof Inet4Address`.

Comment: Whoops, I changed the wording to remove ambiguity. If I wanted to list only the IP addresses for the Interfaces that I mentioned, how would I do that?

Comment: So the problem is you don't know which interface you want to use? The first three octets of the Mac address identify the vendor, you could blacklist the virtual interfaces or whitelist your vendor

Answer (score 0):

use this code

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;
import static java.lang.System.out;

public class ListNets {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws SocketException {
        Enumeration<NetworkInterface> nets = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces();
        for (NetworkInterface netint : Collections.list(nets))
            displayInterfaceInformation(netint);
    }

    static void displayInterfaceInformation(NetworkInterface netint) throws SocketException {
        out.printf("Display name: %s\n", netint.getDisplayName());
        out.printf("Name: %s\n", netint.getName());
        Enumeration<InetAddress> inetAddresses = netint.getInetAddresses();
        for (InetAddress inetAddress : Collections.list(inetAddresses)) {
            out.printf("InetAddress: %s\n", inetAddress);
        }
        out.printf("\n");
     }
}
```

Comment: While this answer is probably correct and useful, it is preferred if you [include some explanation along with it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/159034) to explain how it helps to solve the problem. This becomes especially useful in the future, if there is a change (possibly unrelated) that causes it to stop working and users need to understand how it once worked.